# yaml extension error ( Incorrect type. Expected "string".yaml-schema: pubspec.yaml )

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml

[image]

Recently I created a flutter project and opened the "YAML", getting some error from "YAML" extension. How can I solve this? Is the only solution to uninstall the extension or how to overcome this without uninstalling this extension?

Tried flutter clean, repair, etc. but nothing was helpful.

Errors are:

1 Incorrect type. Expected "string". `yaml-schema: pubspec.yaml`

2 Property flutter is not allowed. `yaml-schema: pubspec.yaml`

3 Property cupertino_icons is not allowed. `yaml-schema: pubspec.yaml`

4 Property flutter_test is not allowed. `yaml-schema: pubspec.yaml`

5 etc.

Using flutter version is 2.8.1

"YAML" (extension) version v1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update VSCode's `YAML` extension to at least `1.5.1` to resolve the error. Flutter will work as it is with the errors too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue with VSCode since this afternoon, everything worked well before. I've tried forcing the schema via `# yaml-language-server: $schema=<urlToTheSchema>` and `yaml.schemas` setting, but no luck.

Edit: could be related to upgrading to yaml extension v1.5.0 (cf: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/708)
Temporarily downgrading back to 1.4.0 no longer throws errors.

Comment: i'm also downgrade the extension to 1.4.0 ,working fine . it's temporary solutions ,i think new version has some schema issue ,

Answer (score 2):

I reload the YAML extension and the error gone

Comment: This ~windows~ solution worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

The YAML extension is using an incorrect schema to validate your YAML file. Ensure that:

- your file does contain a correct `# yaml-language-server: $schema=<urlToTheSchema>` comment or at least does *not* contain a wrong one.
- your `yaml.schemas` setting does not associate your file via glob pattern with an incorrect schema.

The correct schema would be `https://json.schemastore.org/pubspec.json`. See also [Associating Schemas](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml#associating-schemas).

Answer (score 1):

i have uninstall yaml extention
and reinstall and re-open vs code
it fixes the issue for me[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing Yaml extension did the trick for me, in fact I don't really see the need for it since VS Code supports YAML formats by default

Answer (score 0):

For me, in the extensions of VsCode, I looked for **YAML** and I saw there is a "reload required" next to it. did the reload and the errors went away. It is all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by reloading the extension. I went to my extensions tab and the YAML extension needed to be reloaded.

[It does not show here but instead on the left of "Disable", there was a message telling me that I needed to reload the extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCNca.png)